# Guava EventBus Multiple subscribers same tpe

Tags: guava, event-bus

```
import com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus;
import com.google.common.eventbus.Subscribe;

public class Test {

    public static class Processing { }
    public static class ProcessingResults { }
    public static class ProcessingFinished { }

    public static EventBus bus = new EventBus();

    @Subscribe
    public void receiveStartRequest(Processing evt) {
        System.out.println("Got processing request - starting processing");
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void processingStarted(Processing evt) {
        System.out.println("Processing has started");
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void resultsReceived(ProcessingResults evt) {
        System.out.println("got results");
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void processingComplete(ProcessingFinished evt) {
        System.out.println("Processing has completed");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        bus.register(t);
        bus.post(new Processing());
    }
}
```

So, in above example, it can be seen that there are 2 subscribers accepting same type Processing. Now, at the time of post(), which all functions will get called? If the 2 functions receiveStartRequest and processingStarted will get called, then in which order they will be get called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Both your methods will be called and in no predefinite order.

To counter this, just create two extra classes: `ProcessingStarted` and `ProcessingRequested`.

```
public class ProcessingStarted {
  private Processing processing;
  // Constructors
  // Getters/Setters
}


public class ProcessingStarted {
  private Processing processing;
  // Constructors
  // Getters/Setters
}
```

Then call `post(new ProcessingRequested(processing))` and `post(new ProcessingStarted(processing))` when needed, instead of a single `post(processing)`.

Comment: But my question was what would happen if we don't do that? Will both the subscribers then get called?

Comment: @hatellla Actually I started to write that as a comment, but then midway I thought an answer would be better and I forgot to include that part. I've answered that question in my answer now. Sorry for not being more careful :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Oliver

Comment: Thanks! This helps me.